Measurability of a map involving probability measures
Let $X$ be a metrizable topological space and $\mathscr B_X$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on it. Let $\Delta X$ denote the set of probability measures on $(X,\mathscr B_X)$, and let $\mathscr B_{\Delta X}$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the weak-star topology on $\Delta X$ (which is defined as the weakest topology on $\Delta X$ that makes the map $\mathbb P\mapsto\int_X f(x)\,\mathrm d\mathbb P(x)$ continuous for every bounded and continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb R$). In what follows, let $\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}$ denote the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the real line.
Suppose that $(\Omega,\mathscr F)$ is a measurable space and, for each $\omega\in\Omega$, $\mathbb P_{\omega}\in\Delta X$. That is, the space $\Omega$ is supposed to “index” a set of Borel probability measures on $X$ in a measurable manner.
CONJECTURE: The map $\omega\mapsto\mathbb P_{\omega}$ is $\mathscr F/\mathscr B_{\Delta X}$-measurable if and only if the map $\omega\mapsto\mathbb P_{\omega}(A)$ is $\mathscr F/\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}$-measurable for each fixed $A\in\mathscr B_X$.
While I have not checked the details, the “only if” direction does not seem to be difficult to me. The trick is to establish that the map $\mathbb P\mapsto\mathbb P(A)$ is $\mathscr B_{\Delta X}/\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}$-measurable for any given $A\in\mathscr B_X$—see this thread for more details. As this other thread reveals, metrizability of $X$ is essential.
I have trouble proving the “if” direction; in fact, my hunch tells me that it may not even be true without separability of the metric topology on $X$ (which would imply the separability of the weak-star topology on $\Delta X$ as well). Yet, constructing a counterexample has equally eluded me.
I would be very grateful for any hint or insight regarding (i) the proof of the “if” direction; or (ii) a counterexample showing that separability is indispensable.

UPDATE: The “if” direction fails whenever $\mathscr B_{\Delta X}$ strictly includes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets of the form $\{\mathbb P\in\Delta X\,|\,\mathbb P(A)\in E\}$, where $A\in\mathscr B_X$ and $E\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}$. This is because if one takes $\Omega\equiv\Delta X$ with $\omega\mapsto\mathbb P_{\omega}$ being the identity map on $\Delta X$ and $\mathscr F$ to be the generated $\sigma$-algebra just described, then $\omega\mapsto\mathbb P_{\omega}(A)$ (i.e., $\mathbb P\mapsto\mathbb P(A)$) is $\mathscr F/\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}$-measurable for each $A\in\mathscr B_X$ but the identity map on $\Delta X$ is not $\mathscr F/\mathscr B_{\Delta X}$-measurable. I would still very much appreciate an example that explicitly shows the possibility $\mathscr F\subset\mathscr B_{\Delta X}$ (strictly).

The question seems to boil down to whether the Borel and Baire $\sigma$-algebras on $\Delta X$ can differ for nonseparable $X$.

I think that the book  by O. Kallenberg. "Random Measures, Theory and Applications", Springer 2017 addresses  some of  your questions.

@LiviuNicolaescu Thank you for this reference. However, Kallenberg assumes separability throughout the relevant discussion (Chapter 4). I have already convinced myself that the “if” direction of my conjecture cannot hold without separability, so I would be interested to see a specific counterexample showing what may go awry without separability.

@MichaelGreinecker That’s an interesting perspective. The Baire $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the compact $G_{\delta}$ sets, right? Without separability, isn’t there a concern that even $\mathscr F$ is “too rich” (albeit less rich than the Borel $\sigma$-algebra) to be captured by compact $G_{\delta}$ sets?

@triple_sec I would take it to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that makes all real-valued continuous functions measurable.

@MichaelGreinecker Thank you, this seems to be useful insight. What I managed to do thus far is show that if $X$ is uncountable with the discrete metric, then any collection of Dirac measures is $G_{\delta}$ with respect to the weak-star topology on $\Delta X$ (and hence Borel measurable). I feel, but don’t yet know, that such collections cannot all be included in the Baire $\sigma$-algebra.

If $X$ is metrizable, then so is $\Delta X$. Hence the Baire and the Borel $\sigma$-algebras on $\Delta X$ coincide.

@user95282 I don’t think metrizability of $X$ alone guarantees that of $\Delta X$. You need additional structure on $X$ (such as compactness or at least separability).

@triple_sec You are right. $\Delta X$ may not be metrizable when there are measurable cardinals.

@MichaelGreinecker I wonder if you could offer a more detailed insight into how the families (i) ${\mathbb P\in\Delta X,|,\mathbb P(A)\in E}$ for $A\in\mathscr B_X$ and $E\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}$; and (ii) ${\mathbb P\in\Delta X,|,\phi(\mathbb P)\in E}$ for $\phi:\Delta X\to\mathbb R$ continuous with respect to the weak-star topology and $E\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}$ supposedly generate the same $\sigma$-algebra on $\Delta X$.

You can approximate a bounded continuous (or just measurable) function $f$ uniformly from below by a sequence of simple functions $(f_n)$ and integrals of simple functions are measurable if evaluations are. Now, ${\mu: \int f~\mathrm d\mu>r}=\bigcup_n {\mu: \int f_n~\mathrm d\mu>r}$.

@MichaelGreinecker Doesn’t this argument implicitly presuppose that every weak-star-continuous function $\phi:\Delta X\to\mathbb R$ can be represented as an integral $\mu\mapsto\int f,\mathrm d\mu$ for some bounded and continuous $f:X\to\mathbb R$? Is there some kind of Riesz-representation-theorem stuff going on here? While the weak-star topology is the weakest topology making all such integral functions continuous, aren’t there other continuous functions that are not of the form of an integral?

I think you are right. I thought about embedding the space in a large product of unit intervals, and all continuous functions there can depend on only countably many coordinates. But a continuous function on the subspace may not extend to the whole product space.

A counterexample based on the comment by triple_sec:
Let $X$ be a discrete metric space of cardinality larger than continuum.
It follows that for every countable set $\mathcal{C}$ of subsets of $X$
there exist two points $x,y\in X$ such that
$$
(1) \quad\quad \forall A\in\mathcal{C} : \quad x\in A \iff y \in A .
$$
The set $D$ of Dirac measures $\delta_x$, $x\in X$, is closed in $\Delta X$.
Suppose that $D$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets
$\{\mathbb{P} \in \Delta X \mid \mathbb{P}(A)\in E\}$.
Then there are a countable set $\mathcal{C}$ of subsets of $X$
and a countable set $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$
such that $D$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma \mathcal{S}$ generated by
$$
\mathcal{S} = \{ \{\mathbb{P} \in \Delta X \mid \mathbb{P}(A)\in E\} 
              \mid A\in \mathcal{C}, E \in \mathcal{F} \}
$$
As noted above, there are two points $x,y\in X$ such that (1). Then
$$
\delta_x \in T \iff \delta_y \in T \iff \frac{1}{2} ( \delta_x + \delta_y ) \in T,
$$
for every $T\in\mathcal{S}$, hence also for every $T \in \sigma \mathcal{S}$.
For $D\in \sigma \mathcal{S}$ we get
$\frac{1}{2} ( \delta_x + \delta_y ) \in D$, a contradiction.
UPDATE: As triple_sec points out in the comment, it is not obvious why $D$ should be closed in $\Delta X$. But $D$ is $G_\delta$, which is enough for it to be a counterexample.
We can still get $D$ to be closed if desired by limiting the size of $X$. In fact, $D$ is closed in $\Delta X$ if and only if the cardinality of $X$ is less than the first measurable cardinal.

THANK YOU SO MUCH for this amazing answer! Just one minor quibble: I could not show that $D$ is closed in $\Delta X$, but it is $G_{\delta}$ at any rate, which makes no difference to your proof. (The set $O^x_n\equiv{\mathbb P\in\Delta X,|,\mathbb P({x})>(n-1)/n}$ is weak-star open for every $x\in X$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, and so is $\overline O_n\equiv\bigcup_{x\in X}O_n^x$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$. Now, $D=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\overline O_n$.)

For the record, I also posted this question on Mathematics Stack Exchange with a bounty for enhanced visibility. If you would like to repost your answer there (or just a link to it), I will award the bounty to you. Thank you again!

Just for my own reference, let me record here how (1) follows. Let $\mathcal C\subseteq 2^X$ be a (non-empty) countable family. Define, for every $x\in X$, $\mathcal C_x\equiv{A\in\mathcal C,|,x\in A}$ and define the function $F:X\to2^{\mathcal C}$ as $F(x)\equiv\mathcal C_x$ for every $x\in X$. Since $2^{\mathcal C}$ has cardinality at most that of the continuum, it follows that $F$ cannot be injective, so that there exist $x,y\in X$ with $\mathcal C_x=\mathcal C_y$ yet $x\neq y$.

This illustrates a strategy for answering questions in MathOverflow: Submit two answers --- 1. yes, 2. no. One of them will be correct (as long as you are not an intuitionist)! (-:||

It’s a good thing then that I didn’t ask about a proof of or a counterexample to the continuum hypothesis within the confines of ZFC. :-D

Case I: There exists a real-measurable cardinal $\kappa$. Then a discrete space $X$ of cardinality $\kappa$ is a counterexample to the conjecture.
Denote by $\mathcal{A}$ the $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets of $X$. Let $\mu \colon \mathcal{A} \to [0,1]$ be a probability measure that witnesses the real-measurability of $\kappa$. The following lemma is probably well-known, although I don't have a reference on hand.
Lemma. For any countable set $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ there exists another witnessing measure $\nu \colon \mathcal{A} \to [0,1]$, $\nu\neq\mu$, such that $\mu$ and $\nu$ agree on $\mathcal{C}$.
By the lemma, the Borel subset $\{\mu\}$ of $\Delta X$ is not in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets of the form $\{\mathbb{P}\in\Delta X \mid \mathbb{P}(A)\in E\}$.
Case II: There are no real-measurable cardinals. Then the "if" direction of the conjecture holds.
In this case every finite $\sigma$-additive Borel measure on a metric space $X$ is $\tau$-additive, hence $\Delta X$ with the weak-star topology is metrizable.
UPDATE: As pointed out by triple_sec, the argument in Case II is not complete. It still remains to be proved that the conjecture follows from the metrizability of $\Delta X$.
SECOND UPDATE: As the other answer shows, this is not only incomplete but also incorrect.

Thank you for your answer. I don’t seem to fully understand your arguments, though. In particular, I wonder in Case II (i) how the non-existence of real-measurable cardinals implies that every countably additive probability measure on $(X,\mathscr B_X)$ is $\tau$-additive; (ii) how that, in turn, implies that the weak-star topology on $\Delta X$ is metrizable; and (iii) how the metrizability of that topology implies that $\mathscr B_{\Delta X}\subseteq\mathscr F$. Do these implications follow from Fremlin’s treatise?

@triple_sec Answers to (i) and (ii) are in sections 7.2 and 8.3 of Bogachev's "Measure Theory" (2007). Answer to (iii) will take longer.

I guess (iii) would follow from this. Suppose that the weak-star topology is metrizable with a metric $\pi$. If $F\subseteq\Delta X$ is non-empty and closed, can it be shown that the distance function $\mathbb P\mapsto\pi(\mathbb P,F)\equiv\inf{\pi(\mathbb P,\mathbb P'),|,\mathbb P'\in F}$ is $\mathscr F$-measurable? Would this hold even if the weak-star topology is not separable, merely metrizable?

Could you please add a little more detail as to how the Lemma in Case I implies that ${\mu}\notin\sigma({{\mathbb P\in\Delta X,|,\mathbb P(A)\in E},|,A\in\mathscr B_X\text{ and }E\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}})$? It “feels” correct, and I presume the key would be to construct some family of sets $\mathscr E$ that (i) is a $\sigma$-algebra; (ii) includes ${{\mathbb P\in\Delta X,|,\mathbb P(A)\in E},|,A\in\mathscr B_X\text{ and }E\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}}$; and (iii) omits ${\mu}$, but the operationalization of this insight eludes me.

I think I got it (although I would appreciate any feedback regarding whether my argument is correct). Fix the $\mu\in\Delta X$ of Case I. For any $\mathscr C\subseteq 2^X$, define $$\mathscr S_{\mathscr C}\equiv{\nu\in\Delta X,|,\nu(A)=\mu(A)\text{ for all }A\in\mathscr C}.$$ For any $W\subseteq\Delta X$, let $\mathscr T_W$ be the collection of all those $\mathscr C\subseteq 2^X$ for which either $\mathscr S_{\mathscr C}\cap W$ or $\mathscr S_{\mathscr C}\cap W^{\mathsf c}$ is empty. [cont’d]

Finally, let $\mathscr E$ denote the collection of those $W\subseteq\Delta X$ for which there exists a countable $\mathscr C\subseteq 2^X$ such that $\mathscr C\in\mathscr T_W$. It is not difficult to verify that $\mathscr E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra such that ${\mathbb P\in\Delta X,|,\mathbb P(A)\in E}\in\mathscr E$ for every $A\subseteq X$ and $E\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}$, yet ${\mu}\notin\mathscr E$ by the Lemma.

@triple_sec That looks right. Or summed up another way: If a set is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by some set $\mathcal{Z}$ of sets then it is also in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a countable subset of $\mathcal{Z}$.

Thank you for the feedback!

Here is an update. Let $\mathscr S$ be the collection of sets of the form $$\left{\mathbb P\in\Delta X\text{ such that }\left|\int_{x\in X}f(x),\mathrm d\mathbb P(x)-y\right|<\varepsilon\right},$$ where $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is bounded and continuous, $y\in\mathbb R$, and $\varepsilon>0$. By definition, $\mathscr S$ is a subbase for the weak-star topology on $\Delta X$. If $X$ is metrizable, then $\mathscr S$ and ${{\mathbb P\in\Delta X,|,\mathbb P(A)\in E},|,A\in\mathscr B_X\text{ and }E\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}}$ generate the same $\sigma$-algebra on $\Delta X$. [cont’d below]

[cont’d from above] If $X$ is metrizable but not separable, then $\Delta X$ cannot be separable (even if it may be metrizable, like in Case II). For this reason, I have serious doubts as to the possibility that the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\mathscr S)$ generated by the topological subbase $\mathscr S$ and the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by all open sets could coincide even without the existence of real-measurable cardinals. This suggests to me that a counterexample could be constructed within the confines of ZFC.

Here is another thought. In Case II, each probability measure on $(X,\mathscr B_X)=(\mathbb R,2^{\mathbb R})$ is countably supported: for each $\mathbb P\in\Delta X$, there is a sequence $(x_n){n\in\mathbb N}$ in $X$ such that $\sum{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P({x_n})=1$. Yet, could a counterexample be constructed using the set of finitely supported probability measures? It is $G_{\delta\sigma}$ (so it’s in $\mathscr B_X$), but my intuition tells me that there are “too many” finite sets for it to be included in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by ${\mathbb P\in\Delta X,|,\mathbb P(A)\in E}$.

@triple_sec Yes, that will work, at least for $X$ of cardinality larger than continuum. And the counterexample is the set $X$ itself embedded in $\Delta X$.

Do you have a detailed construction in mind? For the life of me, I can’t figure out how to operationalize the intuition.
